# Items overlapping (different size items) in Masonry Itemscontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, masonry

I am trying to implement the Dashboard with different size of widgets in it. User can increase or decrease each widget like this:
[image]

In order to implement this when I searched in google, came to know Masonry Itemscontrol (available in the git hub https://github.com/Lizzaran/WPF-Masonry).

It works perfectly for items in different size unless user tries to give the gap Like this: 
[image]

Here is the major code in Masonry Itemscontrol

```
private void UpdateUI1()
{
    try
    {
        var matrix = new List<int[]> { new[] { 0, (int)this.ActualWidth, 0 } };
        var hMax = 0;
        var temp = this.Parent as ScrollViewer;
        var allControls = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as Visual;

        var onlyRadLegend = allControls.ChildrenOfType<FrameworkElement>().ToList()
        .Where(a => a.GetType().ToString() != null

        && a.GetType().ToString() == "DragAndDrop.Testing" || a.GetType().ToString() == "DragAndDrop.EmptyWidget").ToList();  
        foreach (var child in onlyRadLegend)
        { 
            var element = child as FrameworkElement; 
            if (element != null)
            {
                var size = new[] { (int)element.ActualWidth + this.Spacing, (int)element.ActualHeight + this.Spacing };
                var point = this.GetAttachPoint(matrix, size[0]);
                matrix = this.UpdateAttachArea(matrix, point, size);
                hMax = Math.Max(hMax, point[1] + size[1]);
                this.UpdateAlignment(element);
                var oldThickness = element.Margin;
                if (Math.Abs(oldThickness.Left - point[0]) > 1 || Math.Abs(oldThickness.Top - point[1]) > 1)
                {
                    this.SetPosition(element, point[1], point[0]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

protected virtual void SetPosition(FrameworkElement element, int newTop, int newLeft)
{
    if (element != null)
    {
        element.Margin = new Thickness(newLeft, newTop, 0, 0);
    }
}

private int[] GetAttachPoint(List<int[]> mtx, int width)
{
    mtx.Sort(this.MatrixSortDepth);
    var max = mtx[mtx.Count - 1][2];
    for (int i = 0, length = mtx.Count; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (mtx[i][2] >= max)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (mtx[i][1] - mtx[i][0] >= width)
        {
            return new[] { mtx[i][0], mtx[i][2] };
        }
    }
    return new[] { 0, max };
}

private List<int[]> UpdateAttachArea(List<int[]> mtx, int[] point, int[] size)
{
    mtx.Sort(this.MatrixSortDepth);
    int[] cell = { point[0], point[0] + size[0], point[1] + size[1] };
    for (int i = 0, length = mtx.Count; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (mtx.Count - 1 >= i)
        {
            if (cell[0] <= mtx[i][0] && mtx[i][1] <= cell[1])
            {
                mtx.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else
            {
                mtx[i] = this.MatrixTrimWidth(mtx[i], cell);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.MatrixJoin(mtx, cell);
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Please read [ask] and instead of linking to everything, provide a [mcve]

Comment: ADDED FULL CODE BUT WAS UNABLE TO POST

Comment: You should [edit] your question, don't try to post additional information as answer. However, be careful with adding full code... depending on your problem it might be to much (read about [mcve], as JoSSte suggested)

Comment: Hope my edit is sufficient

Comment: @JoSSte any suggestion on this issue.

Comment: @JoSSte this is WPF platform , not HTML.